# Upload image in CKEditor 4: What JSON parameters are required from upload script?

Tags: file-upload, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor 4.16.2 with the following plugins:

```
filebrowser
uploadimage
uploadwidget
```

I'm not using CKFinder.

My config includes:

```
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/path/to/upload.php?type=image';
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserUploadMethod = 'form';
```

My upload.php script is:

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
if($type == 'image'){

    $allowed_extension = array("png","jpg","jpeg");
    $file_extension = pathinfo($_FILES["upload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(in_array(strtolower($file_extension),$allowed_extension)){       
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['upload']['name'])){
        $url = "/$pathToUploadedImageDir/".$_FILES['upload']['name'];
      
        // This works for drag and drop, and paste, but not for image upload
        // What to echo here?
        echo json_encode( array('uploaded'=> 1, 
           'filename' => $_FILES['upload']['name'], 
           'url' => $url ) ) ;

       } else {        
            echo "Image not uploaded";
       }
    }
    exit;
}
```

The above works fine for drag and drop, and for pasting a screen shot.

However, when I upload an image in the Upload tab of the Image window, it successfully uploads the image to the correct directory, but what I see next is the text of the JSON object (returned from my upload.php script) which appears in place of the "Upload" button. Then nothing else happens.

What I'm expecting to happen is for the "Image info" tab to open and to see the image preview and the image URL and width and height populated (as happens in the CKEditor example pages (which use CKFinder), but not mine).

There are no errors appearing in the console.

So what do I need to echo out in my upload.php? Or is there something else not configured properly? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I find the documentation is rather inadequate for those of us that aren't coding CKEditor continuously.

My first attempts at this problem were for the drag & drop and paste cases. I was using `echo "<script ...</script>";` which I saw in several cases, and I kept seeing errors because it was insisting on a JSON return from the server.

Then it wasn't clear what that JSON had to contain. I actually finally found it via an answer here on Stackoverflow and afterwards came across it in the documentation.

So then I needed to set up the ordinary upload situation and (as my question shows), the JSON output didn't do it for me.

Then (once again, on a forum answer), I saw that I need to do the output as a `<script>`.

This is what eventually worked:

```
$funcNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'];
$message = "Image uploaded successfully.";
echo "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message');</script>";
```

It would have helped a lot if the documentation had code samples for "plain vanilla" (non CKFinder) uploads, divided into plain "Upload"; and "Drag & drop and paste" cases.

Early on I got the impression I needed the (very bloated) CKFinder and wasted time trying to get it to work. It's not needed for these cases.